# handlebars assign object value

Tags: node.js, express, variables, handlebars.js, registerhelper

I'm using handlebars with express in my app.
I need to assign values to an object. i.e

```
pagination : { page : 1, pageCount : 500 }
```

object is passing from controller.
In front end I can access it using something like this on handlebars -

```
 {{{ pagination }}}
```

Now I need to change the "page" & "pageCount" variable values of "pagination" object.

Since handlebars doesn't support changing/assigning variable values inbuilt, I'm stuck with it for a while. Can anyone help me out with a custom helper to do this please ?

Comment: Why do you need changing pagination on client side? This is backend responsibility. To control `pageCount` and `page` you can ether set by something like `itemsPerPage` (this has impact on your `pageCount`) or pick page # on your pagination panel (this will send you data items fir your page and actual page #)

Comment: Hi, I'm using ajax call to browse pages on a table. So, I need to change it on client side.

Comment: Provide snippet where are you trying to achieve that